# Decrypt session of rails by PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, session

Accroding to what i learn, rails session encrypt(AES 256 CBC ) and verify (HMAC (SHA1)).
Now i have already had session:

```
_pdca_session: UFZZbW1qRkxPK3RFWTFRY252S0NTanZFZlp0KzhIQTZYakF3Z09leG5kNmRNMjVjdHVYM1RUZzhCb0EzN3FkMC8rc2tQOGNVVXZ1MEI4dFRqekJNRk5QL0V3V1dSbHZHSFBmMG1aYUlaMDJCUk9vcnNqaDJRNkxiaGRWeERkSmNQOWZOZHlNVmRZSVZOVEF2Q0NId0d4eVUzZ1NaaGFZUlBxYml4NVBrSzRSNWlCQWN5YTJqM1hod0FyNGtQcXhNbzlpQlZvcysrOVVXcE1DOU9rcTJ4RmZXUEx0YTY3V0RFVy9rYlAxbEQ1bU9vRFpVbXhPcjRjWXRFNDAzYldXcDZuSVFlU2NzUWVackVhRUxEWFg3YytVM2s3U3YvbFFXWGJoTk95MEtBY3c9LS1UR01CK3ltTmtVSjMvTHlzOXF2NmdBPT0%3D--e701c43bb3e73edf1302219cf56ec71dcc026fe1
```

How can i decrypt this session by PHP ?
The purpose is get user_id in it.

Update1:
I also have secret key base in rails app

Comment: I also have secret key base in rails app

Comment: Please edit your question to add useful information, instead of hiding them in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am already resolved it, but i must use package nodejs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rails-session-decoder
And in PHP, i will use exec function to executing js script for descrypt session.

```
  exec(env('NODE_PATH') . " $nodeJsPath $secretKey $sessionRails 2>&1", $out, $err);
```

Hope it will help someone.